# Convolving Image to Lower Resolution

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, fft, convolution

I have two astronomy images in fits format having different resolutions. I would like to convolve the higher resolution image to the lower resolution one. I would presume these are the following steps to be performed.

1. Deconvolve the higher resolution image to get the original signal.
2. Convolve the original signal with new convolution filter (point spread function) to get the final image.

I am trying to avoid doing a deconvolution using python because I am not sure if these methods are reliable for radio astronomy images.

I thought of doing fourier and inverse fourier transforms to get around this. Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
image=fits.open(directory+file1)
test=image[0].data #test is the image convolved with the old beam 
#Using Convolution Theorem
test1=np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.fft2(test)*np.fft.fft2(new_beam)/np.fft.fft2(old_beam))
```

When I try to plot this, using:

```
plt.imshow(test1, interpolation='none', origin='lower')
plt.xlabel('x [pixels]')
plt.ylabel('y [pixels]')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

My images do not look like convolved images. Can someone point out what am I doing wrong? Secondly, how should I normalise my intensity values. I know that for one fourier transform you should do absF(x)/len(x). How would I go about it if I have to perform an operation like above?

Comment: If just want a quick resize solution you can have a look at [skimage's resize](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize),

Comment: @ImanolLuengo I did use skimage resize earlier in the program so that the images have the same dimensions. But I need to convolve this image with the new beam (convolution filter) after deconvolving with the old beam.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is four years too late but this is carried out by the radio interferometric python package [CASA](https://casadocs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). This can be done in two steps you can as you rightly pointed out deconvolve the gaussian PSF and then convolve to a smoother resolution. You are looking for the two following tasks in particular [imsmooth](https://casadocs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/tt/casatasks.analysis.imsmooth.html) to convolve and the [deconvolve](https://casadocs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/tt/casatasks.imaging.deconvolve.html) to remove the existing PSF. However you may want to note that the convolution of two gaussians results in a third with a mean as the sums of the means and the std deviation as the square root of the std deviations added in quadrature.

Finally for the flux normalization you have to normalize by the are of the PSF in either case. Hope this helps.